# Simplify $(\sqrt{x}) + x + 2 = (\sqrt{y}) + y + 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$\sqrt{x} + x + 2 = \sqrt{y} + y + 2$

I've simplified as follows:

$\sqrt{x} + x = \sqrt{y} + y$, square both sides

$x + x^2 = y + y^2$

It seems obvious that $x = y$ but I can’t get to that solution by algebraic means.

Comment: Careful. That's not quite what you get when you square both sides. What is $(x+\sqrt x)^2$?

Comment: sub $u=\sqrt{x}, v=\sqrt{y}$ if it helps

Comment: @JohnFernley - taking care of the fact you will create a family of solutions with $u + v = -1$ that don't solve the original equation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $x-y=(\sqrt x +\sqrt y)(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)$

Comment: where do want to go ?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite it in the form $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}=y-x$

Comment: Or $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})=(y-x)(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}).$

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct formula if you want to square: $ (\sqrt{x} +x)^2 = x^2 + 2x\sqrt{x} +x$.

Answer (score 0):

both $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are roots of a quadratic equation:
$$
t^2+t + c=0
$$
hence either $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$ or $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=-1$

Comment: Assuming $x,y$ are real, we can reject the second option.

Answer (score 0):

It's psychologically easier to substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $v=\sqrt{y}$, to get
$$
u+u^2=v+v^2
$$
taking into account that $u\ge0$ and $v\ge0$. This can be rewritten as
$$
(u-v)+(u^2-v^2)=0
$$
or
$$
(u-v)+(u-v)(u+v)=0
$$
that can be rewritten as
$$
(u-v)(1+u+v)=0.
$$
Since $1+u+v>0$, this implies $u-v=0$, that is, $u=v$ and so the solution is
$$
x=y\ge0.
$$
The last condition is because you need $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$, so those numbers must be non negative.